# Linq group by multiple elements and get the count

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following json file:

```
[{"fruits": ["strawberry"]}, {"fruits": ["mango"]}, {"fruits": ["strawberry", "kiwi"]}]
```

I have the following class

```
class shake
{
    public List<string> fruits = new List<string>();
}
```

I know this will give me all unique fruits:

```
var fruits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<shake>>(json);

var shakes = fruits
    .GroupBy(t => t.fruits[0])
    .Select(group => new
    {
         fruit = group.Key,
         Count = group.Count()
    })
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

I'm trying to get a sorted list with the most popular fruits.
Is it possible to group by multiple elements and get the frequency? is possible to do it with linq?

Comment: what is wrong with your code? which part is not working? It looks like It is what you are lookibng

Comment: To get the group by each individual fruit works fine, I just want to know if it is possible to get a group by combination like ""strawberry", "kiwi""

Comment: You're only looking at the first fruit in each shake.  To get all of them do `shake.SelectMany(x => x.fruits)` then you can group on that.

Comment: Do you want to sort fruits by popularity or the composition of shakes by popularity? If you want to group by fruits see my answer below. If you want to sort unique shakes by popularity then you need to implement the IEquatable<Shake> interface and a proper GetHashCode, Then you can group by the shakes themselves. I suggest you sort the fruits in each shakes so that two shakes with the same fruits in a different order are not considered different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your example, you are missing the kiwi. I think what you are after is the `SelectMany` function in Linq.

```
public class Shake
{
    public List<string> Fruits = new List<string>();
}

var list =
(
    from shake in shakes
    from fruit in shake.Fruits
    group fruit by fruit into fruitGroup
    let category = new { Fruit = fruitGroup.Key, Count = fruitGroup.Count() }
    orderby category.Count descending
    select category
).ToList();
```

Comment: made a couple of changes. Please note the uppercases in the definition of the Shake class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what final result you are looking for. How close is this?

```
class Shake
{
    public List<string> fruits = new List<string>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string json = "[{\"fruits\": [\"strawberry\"]}, {\"fruits\": [\"mango\"]}, {\"fruits\": [\"strawberry\", \"kiwi\"]}]";

    List<Shake> fruitList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shake>>(json);

    var shakes = fruitList.SelectMany(x => x.fruits)
        .GroupBy(t => t)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            fruit = group.Key,
            Count = group.Count()
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shakes));
}
```

The output is:

> [{"fruit":"strawberry","Count":2},{"fruit":"mango","Count":1},{"fruit":"kiwi","Count":1}]

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits.SelectMany(x=>x.fruits).GroupBy(x=>x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Count())
```

here we on the output get the dictionary where key is name of fruit and value is the count